# How to launch new app switcher tab in Android?

Tags: android

Suppose I have a single Android app. How can I make that app launch a new tab in the app switcher? For example, the Gmail app does this when you write a new message, it opens the message editor in a new tab within the app switcher.

(P.S., the reason I want to do this is to fork the Google Chrome app and restore merged tabs, let me know if interested).

Comment: [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT), along with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Where do you plant the flag poles? Got a code example?

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_*` flags go on the `Intent` used for `startActivity()`. "Got a code example?" -- much to my surprise, no. I'll have to fix that someday.

Comment: I suppose that gives me enough info to go have a meeting with Google.com. Thanks!