# How does chrome on android manage to show tabs in task switcher?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

Short question: How does (or did) Google Chrome on Android manage to show its tabs in the Android OS task switcher (or "running apps switcher")?

What should I do (preferring Java) to let my app (instances, activities or whatever I need) appear there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40940525/115145

Comment: Removed [tag:google-chrome-app] tag since it's unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on CommonsWares answer I got the following solution:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MultipleInstancesActivity.class)
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(i)
```

The new document flag lets each new task appear in the task switcher. Unfortunately that works only on Android 5.0 (Api 21) and newer versions. I found no way to achieve something like that for Android 4.

Tips for Android 4 Developers: New Task Flags work - You may implement your own task switcher just for your app. Android provides methods for checking for running tasks and switching between them.